# Map one of tuple elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to map one of elements of a tuple simply in typescript?
I'm looking for a gentle abstraction over the following operation

```
const arr: [string, string][] = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

const f = (str: string): number => str.length

arr.map((row) => [row[0], f(row[1])])
```

my first attempt was to implement it like

```
function mapSnd<A, B, C>(arr: [A, B][], f: (B) => C): [A, C][] {
    return arr.map((row) => [row[0], f(row[1])])
}
```

but it doesn't scale up well (for three elements tuple i would need to define new set of functions and so on), so I'm looking for a generic solution

Comment: It's not clear how you want to generalize this. Which members would `f` get applied to for a 3-tuple? a 4-tuple?

Comment: I'd like to have separate methods for each element of tuple, e.g in 3-tuple it'd like to have `mapFst`, `mapSnd`, `mapThr`. I know that i can write them by my own for e.g. 0..22 tuples and publish it in npm, but i wonder if it's possible to maybe generate that code?  or is it possible to build generic solution

Answer (score 0):

You typed great function but there  is a little problem simple - you used B as a parameter name, not type. Use this:

```
const arr: [string, string][] = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
function mapSnd<A, B, C>(arr: [A, B][], f: (second: B) => C): [A, C][] {
    return arr.map(row => [row[0], f(row[1])]);
}
const res = mapSnd(arr, second => second.length); // [string, number][]
```

And for more like mapThrd without separate, there is no way, sorry.

Comment: thanks for help, but that wasn't the real issue :D

Comment: Maybe I found a hacky solution, wait for max 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will allow an arbitrary n-tuple to be used:

```js
const arr: [string, string, string][] = [['a', 'bb', 'zzz'], ['c', 'ddd', 'qqqq'], ['e', 'ffff', 'rrrrr']]

const f = (str: string[]): number[] => str.map(s=>s.length);

const map = new Map();

arr.forEach(row => map.set(row.shift(), f(row)));

for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! But some changes appeared to your array.

```
const arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

function map<A extends any[], I extends number, C>(index: I, array: A[], f: (el: A[I]) => C) {
    return array.map(row => {
        const newRow = [...row];
        row[index] = f(row[index]);
        return newRow as A & Record<I, C>;
    })
}

const string = map(0, arr, str => str.length)[0][1];
const number = map(0, arr, str => str.length)[0][0];
```

Comment: but it seems that the compiler is not able to check arity of the given tuple. for example `map(0, arr, str => str.length)[0][3]` returns undefined, but i would expect to get a compiler error like when i try to execute `arr[0][3]` i get  `Tuple type '[string, string]' of length '2' has no element at index '3'`

Comment: Yes, the code is not ideal but TypeScript isn't perfect. This is the best possible solution but not perfect and ideal either.